# React Native Fetch asynchronous

Tags: react-native, fetch

I have trouble truly understanding asynchronous behavior. I am making a call to a Japanese Database, but because of the asynchronous behavior my calls are one step behind the user's input. For example, the user types in the letter G there will be no response, until the user types in Go. My app will then send a request for a lookup on the letter G while the user is excepting results for Go. Hopefully, that makes a bit of sense.

This is where I make my asynchronous call.

```
sendData(){
        fetch('http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword='+this.state.wordLookUp).then((dictionary) => {

                return dictionary.json();
            }).then((dictionary) => {
                console.log(dictionary);
                this.setState({
                    dictionary:dictionary.data,
                    loading:false
                })

            }).done((dictionary)=>{
                console.log(this.state.dictionary);


            });


    }
```

Right here is where I display the results to the user

```
renderList(){
     if(!this.state.wordLookUp.length){
        this.state.dictionary = null;
     }

     if(!this.state.dictionary){    
      return(
        <View>
        <Text>loading</Text>
        </View>
        )
     }else{

     return this.state.dictionary.map(words => 
            <ScrollView>
            <Text>{words.senses[0].english_definitions}  {words.japanese[0].reading}</Text>
             </ScrollView>

         );
     }
    }
```

My render function is here:

```
render(){   
     return(
     <View>
     <Header/>
       <Fumi            
        label={'Add Englishword....'}
        iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
        iconName={'pencil'}
        iconColor={'#f95a25'}
        onSubmitEditing={(wordLookUp) => {

            this.sendData();    
        dismissKeyboard(); 
        }}
        onChangeText={(wordLookUp) =>{
            this.setState({wordLookUp});
            console.log(wordLookUp);
            this.sendData(); 
            this.renderList();
        }}

       />
     {this.renderList()}
     </View>
    )   

    }
}
```

Here is the dictionary that inspired my design. http://www.nihongodict.com/w/15758/ichiranhyou/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Super useful site! (For someone who's learning Japanese) I think you will need to setup a buffer system to wait until the user is not typing anymore. For example wait 300ms and then take the values and do the fetching. If the user types a letter you will queue the fetch request, but if the user types again you will cancel the previous queue and create a new queue for another 300ms

Comment: Is there a site you can refer me to. I am very new to this language. So any resources would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest it's to wait until the user completes to enter the word or letters that wants to search for. A common approach it's to queue a function for 300ms for example, then if this function is called again within the 300ms, the execution will get delayed again for another 300ms. This way if the user types really fast, you won't be requesting the server for every key stroke, but for the final result.

Here's an example of how you can create a function that runs every X milliseconds, if a new call to the function it's made, then it cancels the previous calls and queue a new call.

```
function createBuffered(callback, buffer) {
  var timerId;

  return function(...params) {
    if (timerId) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    }

    timerId = setTimeout(function(){
      callback.apply(this, params);
    }, buffer);
  };
}
```

First you will have to create a function buffered function, then just called it on every keystroke, it will automatically delay the execution. Here's an example on how to use it.

```
class Testing extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    fetch: '',
  };

  componentWillMount() {
      // This function will be buffered for 300ms
    this.fetchData = createBuffered((query) => {
      // You should make your fetch request here.
      this.setState({
         fetch: query,
      });
    }, 300);
  }

  load(query) {
    // This will be called constantly but nothing will happen until
    // 300ms without activity on the input field
    this.fetchData(query);
  }

  setQuery = (event) => {
    // Just updating the state to save the input
    const query = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      query,
    });
    // Set the queue
    this.load(query);
  }

  render() {
    const { fetch, query } = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>After 300ms, search for: {fetch}</Text>
        <TextInput value={query} onChange={this.setQuery} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Good luck!!

Edit: Here's a running example in reactjs, only the JSX it's a little bit different: https://jsfiddle.net/crysfel/fo7q6wzd/

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it. I will try this and let you know how this works out for me.